# Is it possible to simulate Iphone 3g?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my question is: with the simulator, is possible to simulate the other type of iphone?(3g, 3gs) or only iphone 4?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iPhone Simulator only simulates a small portion of the **software**. It does not emulate **hardware** at all (otherwise it would have been called iPhone *Emulator*).

The only way to test your apps on real-world hardware constraints is to get a paid program account and install your apps on real devices.

Answer (score 1):

Because the hardware differences between the iPhone 3G and the 3GS doesn't affect in the test of applications. The simulator doesn't limit memory usage or CPU speed based on what hardware you've selected, the accelerometer cannot be simulated, so the only difference of consideration is the screen size, that changes between iPhone 4 and 3G/3GS, but not between 3GS and 3G.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. If you try to detect device type on simulator with the following code it'll never return you any version except 'iPhone Simulator'.

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>
+ (NSString *)getDeviceType {
  struct utsname systemInfo;
  uname(&systemInfo);

  return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```